# Полосы прокрутки в chrome при печати

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, печать

[image: Без неё появляются полосы прокрутки и обрезается контент]

в firefox всё отображается нормально и без проблем.

А вот в хроме беда:

Когда включена панель разработчика, то при печати - всё ок.

Без неё появляются полосы прокрутки и обрезается контент.

Один из вариантов уменьшить проценты, но это не лучший вариант.

Comment: Накладная выводится во фрейм? Тогда и печатайте фрейм, а не главный документ. Если выводится в div, то проще переделать на фрейм. Печать фрейма на вскидку не вспомню. Что-то типа `windows.frames['name_of_print_frame'].print()`

Comment: Спасибо. Вы были правы и натолкнули на правильный выход из ситуации.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Печать с `iframe` - `windows.frames['name_of_print_frame'].print()`.